# Playwright runner with cucumber

Tags: angular, cucumber, e2e-testing, gherkin, playwright

Lately I found playwright and it seems really nice. The problem I found is in implementation of cucumber or gherkin syntax generally. While in cypress for example its pretty easy task here it looks like I need to use some other test runner then playwright. Is it true or I am just missing some library/configuration for cucumber in playwright? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: looks like all guides around suggest you to use the cucumber runner, which is sad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cucumber for run your tests and integrate it with playwright. As a starting point you can review this links from Tally Barak that can help you a lot.

Intro article https://tally-b.medium.com/e2e-testing-with-cucumber-and-playwright-9584d3ef3360

starter repo https://github.com/Tallyb/cucumber-playwright

Answer (score 1):

There is also [playwright-bdd](https://github.com/vitalets/playwright-bdd) package that allows to execute BDD scenarios with Playwright runner:

You can write step definitions exactly the same way as for Cucumber:

```js
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber';

Given('I open url {string}', async function (url) {
  await this.page.goto(url);
});

When('I click link {string}', async function (name) {
  await this.page.getByRole('link', { name }).click();
});
```

and use these steps in a feature file:

```
Feature: Playwright site

    Scenario: Check title
        Given I open url "https://playwright.dev"
        When I click link "Get started"
        ...
```

Then update Playwright config with `playwright-bdd` options:

```js
// playwright.config.js
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { defineBddConfig } from 'playwright-bdd';

const testDir = defineBddConfig({
  paths: ['feature/*.feature'],
  require: ['steps/*.ts'],
});

export default defineConfig({
  testDir,
});
```

And finally run tests with the following command:

```bash
npx bddgen && npx playwright test
```